# Does performFetchWithCompletionHandler always *eventually* get called, even if it takes a long time?

Tags: ios

I know all the gumpf that gets regurgitated about how `setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval` is only a request to the OS to be run in the background with a *minimum* frequency, and that the OS will decide when its going to rouse the app based on several factors, and that Apple doesn't specify exactly when the app will get run.

But I have not been able to find any information/past questions on *if* the app will *eventually* get run at some point.
Suppose for example setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval is set to one day and the user is very active on the device and uses the app regularly then one might expect the app might be run every day. But suppose the user does't use the app much and force exits it and also they don't use their phone much in general. Then will the OS still laugh the app in the background at some point? If not every day that at some point, after 2, 34, 5 N, days or whatever.

Yes I know Apple don't say or publish the algorithm, but is there any tribal knowledge/experience regarding if the the app does at some point get run, even if after N day, where N could be large,  instead of the requested 1 day?